# An element in the simplicial homotopy group

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

I am confused with this construction in Goerss Jardine's [*Simplicial Homotopy Theory, pg. 26+27*](http://dodo.pdmi.ras.ru/~topology/books/goerss-jardine.pdf)

[image]
[image]

**Is not $v$ a $0$-simplex? So I suppose we define $v_i$ as the composition $\Delta^n \rightarrow \Delta^0 \xrightarrow{v} X?$**

Comment: Yes, for $0\leq i\leq n-2$ you get $v_i$ by collapsing the $i^{th}$ face of $\Delta^{n+1}$ to a point. Since this face is just a copy of $\Delta^n$ the map that you write down $\Delta^n\rightarrow\Delta^0\xrightarrow{v}X$ describes $v_i$. Try sketching the case $n=2$.

Comment: If you c/p this I will accept your answer. : )